# How to organize multiple Scrapy Spiders and pass data between them?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a problem that is stopping me from progressing my project.
I'll try to explain it as clearly as I can, but I am relatively new to scraping.

- I want to scrape articles from Website A.
- Website A doesn't have articles' content in its HTML code but links to articles on other websites (lets say Website B and Website C)
- I have created a Spider that extracts links from Website A and yields them in JSON format.
- I want to take the extracted links from Website A and scrape the articles from Websites B and C.

Now - I want to create separate Spiders for Website B and Website C (to use them later for scraping those websites directly and not through Website A) and somehow pass scraped data from Website A as arguments to them - but the "somehow" part is what I need your help with.

Thank you :)

EDIT

Anwsering jqc - since I posted my questions I made some developments - this is my code so far.

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Website A Spider'

    start_urls = ['start_url']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('###### Link Parser ######')
        important_news = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "importantNews")]//div[contains(@class, "items")]/a')

        for news in important_news:
            yield {

                'link': news.xpath('./@href').get(),
                'title': news.xpath('.//span[contains(@class, "title")]/text()').get()

            }

            article_url = news.xpath('./@href').get()
            self.logger.info('FOLLOWING URL OF THE ARTICLE')

            if 'Website B' in article_url:
                yield response.follow(article_url, callback=self.parse_Website_B)
            else:
                pass

    def parse_Website_B(self, response):

            yield {
                'Website B article title': response.xpath('//p[contains(@class, "Header_desktopTextElement")]').get()

            }
```

Don't worry about unfinished parsing, that's the least concerning part :)

Right now I am creating separate methods to parse particular websites, but I don't know if that is the optimal way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. Do you have a "Minimal reproducible example" of your project?

Comment: Hi! I just updated my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to see the URL you are trying to crawl. Then I can make some tests and try to decipher your question.
I can give you some hints, I am not sure if I understand you.
If you want to scrape the given URLs from A, you can do it directly into:

```
def parse_Website_B(self, response):

        yield {
            'Website B article title': response.xpath('//p[contains(@class, "Header_desktopTextElement")]').get()

        }
```

You just have to yield the links, I would try with start_requests. Have a look in the documentation [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html).

If you provide the URL, we can try otherwise.

cheers

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
Actually I managed to solve the problem myself with help from the link you gave :)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case will be much ease to create a list of URLs as a global variable in the spyder file, and then use it as a list for requests.

Something like this:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy import signals

URL_LIST = []
DATA_LIST = []

def store_url(*args, **kwargs):
    URL_LIST.append(kwargs['item'])

def store_data(*args, **kwargs):
    DATA_LIST.append(kwargs['item'])

class QuotesSpiderWebsiteA(scrapy.Spider):
    #Your code

class QuotesSpiderWebsiteB(scrapy.Spider):
    # etc...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner()

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def crawl():
        crawler1 = runner.create_crawler(QuotesSpiderWebsiteA)
        crawler2 = runner.create_crawler(QuotesSpiderWebsiteB)
        crawler1.signals.connect(store_url, signals.item_scraped)
        crawler2.signals.connect(store_data, signals.item_scraped)
        yield runner.crawl(crawler1)
        yield runner.crawl(crawler2)
        reactor.stop()

    crawl()
    reactor.run()
    # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
    with open('output.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
        json.dump(DATA_LIST)
```